# DropDownList TextValue is 1st in List

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm a newbie when it comes to asp.net, so grateful for any help.

I have a simple data bound drop down list, with a details view control. I can select a value from the list, hit update and the correct value gets written to the database. Problem is, the control the automatically "resets" to display the 1st value in the list. This would confuse the user and make them think they'd selected the 1st value prior to the update.

The only code-behind code in relation to this drop down list can be found in the ItemUpdating method of the details view control, as follows:

```
DropDownList ddlLoc = (DropDownList)dvYourProfile.FindControl("ddlLocation");
e.NewValues["PreferredLocation"] = ddlLoc.SelectedValue;
```

And here's the code form the aspx page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preferred Location"         
    SortExpression="PreferredLocation">        
    <ItemTemplate>        
        <asp:DropDownList Text='<%# Bind("PreferredLocation") %>' DataSourceID="dsStaticDate" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" />        
    </ItemTemplate>    
    <EditItemTemplate>    
        <asp:DropDownList DataValueField='PreferredLocation' DataSourceID="dsStaticDate" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" />    
    </EditItemTemplate>    
    <InsertItemTemplate>    
        <asp:DropDownList DataValueField='PreferredLocation' DataSourceID="dsStaticDate" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" />    
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsStaticDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM StaticData" />
```

Comment: If you bind from the code behind, you have much more control over what happens with your data bound controls.  I would recommend that you do that.

Comment: But this should be such a simple task - I think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind form the code behind.  The out-of-the-box behavior of binding on the aspx page with the SqlDataSource does not allow you to stop the rebinding of the DropDownList after an event occurs.